# SQL Subqueries in Views

Tags: 7, views

I have a View, with its corresponding SQL query. I want a field to be a subquery ( `SELECT * FROM TABLE table WHERE ...` ) with its corresponding result fields. I don't know if this is allowed, it seems more like a field which is another View in itself, to be called from my View. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirement can fulfill [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

Comment: That's it. It works perfectly. Thank you very much!